# Extension of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-23}]$ by root of $x^3-x+1$ is Galois

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-extensions

$\newcommand{\BA}{\mathbb{A}}$
$\newcommand{\BQ}{\mathbb{Q}}$
$\newcommand{\disc}{\operatorname{disc}}$
Consider the number field $K=\BQ[\sqrt{-23}, \alpha]$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3-x+1$. How can I show that $K/\BQ[\sqrt{-23}]$, or more generally $K/\BQ$, is Galois?

I know that:

- $\disc(\BA \cap \BQ[\sqrt{-23}]) = \disc(\BA \cap \BQ[\alpha]) = -23$.
- $\BQ[\sqrt{-23}]/\BQ$ is degree 2 and Galois. $\BQ[\alpha]/\BQ$ is degree 3 and not Galois.
- $\BA \cap \BQ[\sqrt{-23}]$ has an integral basis $\{1, \sqrt{-23}\}$ and $\BA \cap \BQ[\alpha]$ has an integral basis $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2\}$.

We need to show that the other two roots of $x^3-x+1$ belong to $K$. Somehow the fact that $\disc(\BA \cap \BQ[\alpha]) = -23$ implies this is the "right" polynomial to adjoin a root of.

(The further point of the exercise is to show that $L/K$ is unramified, similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556649/showing-that-a-cubic-extension-of-an-imaginary-quadratic-number-field-is-unramif), and thus to conclude that $K$ is the Hilbert class field of $\BQ[\sqrt{-23}]$. However I am asking a more basic question: I do not know why $K/\BQ[\sqrt{-23}]$ is even Galois.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the splitting field $K$ of $x^3-x+1$. 
Certainly $K$ is Galois over $\Bbb Q$ and indeed over any subfield.
The polynomial is
irreducible, and its discriminant is $-23$ which is not a square.
Therefore the Galois group is $S_3$ and $|K:\Bbb Q|=6$. The quadratic
subextension $L$ is generated by the square root of the discriminant,
so $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-23})\subseteq K$. As $|K:L|=3$ then $K=L(\alpha)$
where $\alpha$ is a zero of $x^3-x+1$.

Comment: Okay, so $\sqrt{-23} \in K$ because it equals a certain determinant, and the existence of the quadratic subextension $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-23}]$ implies $|K:\mathbb{Q}|=6$. Would it be fair to say this method only works because the polynomial is cubic?

Comment: This is neat. Just the other day I was wondering what the class field of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-23}\,)$ was.

Comment: @Arcinde Yes, this exploits cubicness to the utmost!

Comment: @Lubin Your next exercise is to compute the Hilbert class field of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-31})\ \ddot\smile$.

Comment: Awrk. That’s too much of a burden for an old geezer to labor under. (I’ll give it some thought.)

Comment: Oh my, @LordSharktheUnknown, how easy that was. But I’m so foggy on cubic extensions that it never would have occurred to me to try that particular one as the class field of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-31}\,)$ without having seen your explanation above. Thanks!

Comment: @Lubin If only all Hilbert class fields were so easy!